# Getting service fabric cluster name from within container

Tags: docker, containers, azure-service-fabric

I'm currently deploying a Docker container on Service Fabric and looking to implement telemetry by passing my logging service the cluster, node, and container name at runtime.

Both the node that the container is deployed to and the container id is available from within the container through the `Fabric_NodeName`and `COMPUTERNAME` environment variables.

Is there anyway to get the name of the cluster that the container is deployed to at runtime?
[These environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference) are available from within the container but I don't think these give me any information about the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

A Service Fabric cluster does not have a name, however you can give it one yourself and store it using the Property Management API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-index-property-management. The name would then be retrievable across the cluster. Since you're in a container you can only get to this via REST.